# Python 3 - BASIC Simulator

Tags: python, simulator, basic

I'm currently working on a BASIC simulator in Python, as the title suggests.  This program should either print "success" or "infinite loop", depending on which one is true.  Here is my code:

```
def findLine(prog, target):
   for l in range(0, len(prog)):
      progX = prog[l].split()
      if progX[0] == target:
          return l 

def execute(prog):
  location = 0
  while True:
    if location==len(prog)-1: return "success"
    else: return "infinite loop"
    T = prog.split()[location]
    location = findLine(prog, T)
```

FindLine should take an input like this: findLine(['10 GOTO 20', '20 END'], '20') and output the index of prog in which target appears.
execute should take an input like this: execute(['10 GOTO 21', '21 GOTO 37', '37 GOTO 21', '40 END'])

Problem is, the "def execute(prog)" portion of this code is broken, and I need some help fixing it so it does what I describe earlier.  Any help with debugging this would be appreciated, and apologies if this is a little vague -- I'm not quite sure what to write.

Comment: What is the question exactly? What do you mean by *broken*? Could you describe what is happening, and what you'd expect?

Comment: @CharlesBrunet By broken, I just mean that the code isn't functioning as it should be.  What's happening is that it returns "infinite loop" when it should return "success".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to execute your code step by step in a debugger to see what happens. Or just do it mentally.

First, you set `location` to 0. Then, you look if it is equals to the number of lines. If so, you return *success*, if not, you return *infinite loop*. How to you expect the next two lines to be executed?

I think you should redesign the way you detect an infinite loop. Not being currently on the last line isn't a sufficient condition... If you interpreter only handles `GOTO`, then reaching the same line two times could be a good hint. But if you implement more logic, then you should think about detecting the number of times you reach each line, and set a threshold on that.