# How do I keep a list of numbers I have already enountered?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently working on a BASIC simulator in Python, as the title suggests.  Here is my code for this problem:

```
def getBASIC():
   l = []
   x = 1
   while x == 1:
      i = input()
      l.append(i)
      if len(i.split()) != 3:
         x = 0
   return l

def findLine(prog, target):
   for l in range(0, len(prog)):
      progX = prog[l].split()
      if progX[0] == target:
          return l

 def execute(prog):
      location = 0
      visited = [False] * len(prog)
      while True:
        T = prog[location].split()[2]
        location = findLine(prog, T)
        visited[location] = True
      if visited[len(visited)-1] == False:
          return "infinite loop"
      else:
          return "success"
```

The first function does what it is intended to do -- convert input of BASIC code into a list.  The second function, findLine also does what it is intended to do, in that it finds the item which contains the string equal to the input.  The last function, however, I cannot get to work.  I know what I have to do, and that is to check whether or not a part of it has been visited twice.  I cannot figure out how to do this, due to the existence of the while loop.  As a result of this, the second half of that function is just placeholder.  If you could help me figure out how to solve this, it would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python 3 - BASIC Simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832517/python-3-basic-simulator)

Comment: Please, use a title that actually reflects what your question is.

Comment: Two things: 1. In your loop, put a condition to exit if you reach the last line. 2. Instead of using `while True`, put a limit on the number of steps your program can perform (for example: `for i in range(1000000)`)

Comment: @CharlesBrunet I realise that this is technically a duplicate, but I submitted that question too long ago for anyone to really consider answering it.  As well as that, I already accepted your answer.  Problem is, while your answer was helpful and gave me some guidance, it didn't contain any code, and I'm stuck with the actual writing of the code.

Comment: It looks like your third function is trying to detect whether your program will loop forever or eventually halt. You may wish to skip that feature, because it's impossible to solve the [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) for a Turing-complete language (such as BASIC).

Comment: @Kevin Actually, it is possible to detect an infinite loop in Python.  For example, if a line in this program is visited twice, the program causes an infinite loop.  Any ideas how I could adapt this code to do the following: When the program visits a line twice, it returns "infinite loop"; otherwise, it must return "success"?

Comment: I've now changed the topic to reflect your question.

Comment: @LennartRegebro I should have probably done that already.

Comment: @Dan, "if a line in this program is visited twice, the program causes an infinite loop", you sure about that? For example, take the program `10 X = 0; 20 X = X + 1; 30 IF X < 10 THEN GOTO 20; 40 PRINT "DONE";` Line 20 is visited ten times, but it's not an infinite loop. The program will eventually print "DONE".

Answer (score 0):

You keep a list of places that have been visited (you already do this) and then when you encounter a goto, you check if it does to a line that already have been visited, and if it has been visited, you exit.

One mistake right now is that you make a list that is as long as the program is. That's pretty pointless. Just keep a list of the visited line numbers instead, and check with

```
if current_line in visited:
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure how that will work, but would the last item (end) in a list being false after looping for the number of items in that list indicate an infinite loop?  I'm not sure how to do that, though.  What could I implement to make the program count how many times something has been visited?

Comment: @dan: "but would the last item (end) in a list being false after looping for the number of items in that list indicate an infinite loop?" - I can't parse that question.

Comment: @dan: "What could I implement to make the program count how many times something has been visited?"  You have a dictionary with a list of things that are visited, and a number of times it has been visited.

Comment: I tried the last item == False method before, but that would only work if the program checked whether it had looped for the length of the list. How could I do this?  Alternatively, how could I check if a line is repeatedly visited?

Comment: @Dan: I have no idea why you would check if last item == False. "how could I check if a line is repeatedly visited" - I've already answered that: You have a dictionary with a list of things that are visited, and a number of times it has been visited.

Comment: While I do have a list of which items have been listed and which haven't, I don't have a list of how many times each item has been visited; this is what I want to do, but I don't know how to.

Comment: @Dan: You make a dictionary of the line numbers that are visited, and keep in it the number of times it has been visited. Do you know what a dictionary is?

Comment: Yes, I do know what a dictionary is, but I haven't used them much at all.  Did I get them confused with lists?  Sorry.

Comment: @dan: I don't know. But if you know what a dictionary is, then my answer above should be pretty clear.

Comment: Again, I have never really used them. I only really know what they are, vaguely.  I'm rather new to programming.

Comment: @Dan: I understand that. You need to go through some beginners tutorials to get the basics. This one is rather popular: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/

Comment: Thank you.  Though I don't really know about dictionaries, I'm pretty good in other areas of Python.  I'll get back to you once I've learnt what I need to learn.

Comment: All right, I've brushed up on what I need to brush up on and completed the dictionaries section.  So, what would you recommend I do with a dictionary?  You mentioned them above, but it wasn't clear what you said I should try to do with them.

Comment: @Dan: If it's not clear, continue the tutorial. Note: There is no shame in being a newbie and ignorant of programming. We were all newbies once. But SO is not the place to learn basic programming. It's for asking question when you get stuck. You are not stuck yet, because you haven't learnt enough to *be* stuck.

Comment: Fair enough.  Though I am a newbie, (and being 13 doesn't really help) I would disagree with your point that I have not learnt enough to be stuck.  I know pretty much everything up to the level, so to speak, of recursion, and the website I am taking my course on seems to think that I'm at a good enough level to complete this task.  I guess all programmers have weak points, and this is mine.  Or perhaps I should stop learning C++ simultaneously for the time being.  Either way, thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Well, age doesn't matter, just experience. But learning the very different language c++ at the same time could be confusing.

Comment: I suppose so, but I can't choose between the two.  Python is, in my opinion, the best language for aspiring programmers with little to no experience, while C and its variants are very powerful languages that every programmer should learn.  Which do you think would be best for me to learn at this point?

Comment: @Dan: Learn Python first. C is a must-have tool, I agree. C++ is not, like C#, ObjectiveC, Java, Pascal, etc etc that's a language you learn because you want to work on something that requires it. After Python and C you should probably learn one of the functional languages. Which one is of less importance. :-)

Comment: Apologies for not responding for a while, but I've been busy with school.  Back to the problem at hand.  I initiated a dictionary and created keys with for i in range(0, len(prog)).  I think that what I should do next is, for example, some random character to the key of the line that is being visited.  Then, I should test for a key containing two characters.  Am I correct in thinking this, or something along these lines?

Comment: @Dan: What? No, you keep a count of how many times you have visited each line.  `lines[currentline] += 1`.

Comment: And how would I go about doing this?  I understand some of this, in that I have to add the line I have visited to a dictionary and check whether I have visited a line twice that way, but I find "for in" loops pretty difficult.  I may need this dumbing down a bit, with me being a noob and all.  I refuse to skip this question.

Comment: @dan: I don't know why you think you need a for loop. (except for setting the initial keys with `range(0, len(prog))` but you did that already. You might refuse to skip this question, but I'm personally ready to give up soon. :-) Start with going through some book on the topic, from start, to finish. For example this one: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/ You can ask questions on here on SO when you don't understand. Then, come back to this question, and I promise you, it will be perfectly trivial. If it isn't, then give up on programming. :-)

Comment: Well, you're the programmer.  I'll follow your advice and skip this.  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an if statement declaring a line in the visited list to be true when it is encountered in the loop.  This is my solution:

```
    def execute(prog):
       location = 0
       visited=[False]*len(prog)
   while True:
           if location==len(prog)-1:
           return "success"
       if visited[location]==True:
           return "infinite loop"
       if visited[location]==False:
           visited[location]=True
       line2strings=prog[location].split()
       T=line2strings[-1]
       location=findLine(prog, T)
```